# Parsing a csv file in python and saving to a dictionary which is in turn saved to a list

Tags: python, csv

My task is to read the input **`DATAFILE`**, line by line, and for the first 10 lines (not including the header) split each line on "**`,`**" and then for each line, create a dictionary where the key is the header title of the field, and the value is the value of that field in the row.

The function **`parse_file()`** should return a list of dictionaries,
each data line in the file being a single list entry.

Field names and values should not contain extra whitespace, like spaces or newline characters.

My question is this program generates data(list) that has the same value in all its list entries that is the last line of the `csv` file.

```
 import os

 DATADIR = ""
 DATAFILE = "beatles-diskography.csv"


 def parse_file(datafile):
    data = []
    count = 0
    d = 0
    my_dict = dict()
    with open(datafile, "r") as f:
       while d<10:
         for line in f:
            count = count + 1
            if count is 1:
             p = line.split(',')
             length = len(p)
            else:
             r = line.split(',') 
             l = 0
             while l < length:   
              my_dict[p[l].strip('\n')] = r[l].strip('\n')    
              l = l + 1       
             data.append(my_dict)      
             d = d + 1      

    return data

 def test():                      # a simple test of your implementation
     datafile = os.path.join(DATADIR, DATAFILE)

     d = parse_file(datafile)

     firstline = { 'Title':              'Please Please Me',
                   'UK Chart Position':  '1',
                   'Label':              'Parlophone(UK)',
                   'Released':           '22 March 1963',
                   'US Chart Position':  '-',
                   'RIAA Certification': 'Platinum',
                   'BPI Certification':  'Gold'
                   }

     tenthline = { 'Title':              '',
                   'UK Chart Position':  '1',
                   'Label':              'Parlophone(UK)',
                   'Released':           '10 July 1964',
                   'US Chart Position':  '-',
                   'RIAA Certification': '',
                   'BPI Certification':  'Gold'
                   }

     assert d[0] == firstline
     assert d[9] == tenthline


test()
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: But I have a doubt in this logic which should work. It would be great if you could help me figure out why.

Comment: What is your doubt,  what is not working?

Comment: Please specify what exactly is not behaving as you expect.

Comment: see the edit after program execution data has the last value of the csv file (n number of times) n is no; of lines in the csv file

Comment: You keep appending and modifying  the same dict to your list

Comment: But the dict should keep changing according to the line. my_dict will have information of a line and it keeps changing but data doesn't reflect that

Comment: @PythonGuy, no it is not, the csv lib does not add logic it is used to parse files, it is not a magic wand.

Comment: @Pooja, you cannot use a single dict and expect to get different output by appending references to the dict to your list. You have a single object that you are mutating so any changes after you append will be reflected everywhere

Comment: Also never use `is` to test for equality, always use `==` `if count == 1:`, to skip `n` lines with a loop simply use `for _ in range(n):next(f)`

Comment: @Padraic Thanks a lot. It worked. I re-intialized my_dict = dict() at the beginning while traversing every line. So it worked.

Comment: No worries, FWIW,  here are three more pythonic ways to do what you want, http://pastebin.com/mk37UiE6

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I said csv because it would just make it easier, it is not the whole anwer...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example solution using the 'csv' library.

```
import csv

def parse_file(DATAFILE, lines):
    with open(DATAFILE, 'r') as fd:
        dat    = csv.reader(fd)
        header = next(dat) # makes strong assumption that csv has header
        retval = list()

        for index, row in enumerate(dat):
            if (index >= lines): break # restricts number of lines
            retval.append(dict(zip(header, row)))

    return retval

d = parse_file(DATAFILE, 10)
```